# iOS: How to check if there is Data saved in Keychain?

Tags: ios, keychain, autologin

With which method do I check if I have Data saved in my Keychain for a autologin? Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Keychain Services Prog guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1).
In this guide u will find both

1.How to add & find item in keychain, 
and

2.how to get & change attributes & data in keychain item.